# Query Reports from comma separated JSON mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

this is my first question. Apologies if I don't conform with the required rules. I have tried my best and

Problem--
I have a problem with a project am working on. It is medical based. I have these three tables that I need to get reports from
DB structure--

```
diseaseTable which has columns
diseaseID | diseaseName
diseaseID stores an integer i.e 1, 3, 4,..
dieseaseName stores name of disease e.g Hypertension, Malaria, ..e.tc
```

I also have patientsTable which has these key columns

```
patientID - which is an autoincrement int
patientName - name of patient
created_at - date and time of registration of the patient
```

Lastly there is treatment table which contains

```
treatmentID -autoincrement int
patient - contains the id of the patient which is a foreing key of patientsTable
created_at and updated_at for timestamps
diseaseTreated (which is my column of interest) Stores values in json comma separated fields.
```

I have already checked all results from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+comma+separated+fields but none seems to solve my problem. I have checked on ways to restructure mysql schema but i would have too many tables to store the diseases diagnised from each patient. In addition one patient might be diagnosed with multiple diseases and a disease can be added any time. I might have almost 100 of them. If ID of Hypertension is 1 and arthritis is 2 a patient with both will have the 

`diseaseTreated field with "1","2" in the treatment table`

Solution Expected--
I need to get reports for first time a specific disease has been treated for the first time or second time and more i.e revisit for treatment of the same disease (if i wanted to know how many cases of hypertension are for the first time, and how many cases of hypertension are recurrent)

Example - New cases report

```
Disease | New Cases
Hypertension | 4
```

Example - Recurrent cases report

```
Disease | New Cases
Hypertension | 1
Arthritis    | 2
```

Am using Laravel I have attempted a lot of solutions but this is what i find too close to get what I need: Others I have attempted was looping through different array results i have queried from the database by using joins but I havent posted them because they have yielded nothing important.

```
$diseaseID
$countedDiseaseCases = DB::select('select * from treatmentTable where JSON_CONTAINS(diseases, \'[\"'.$diseaseID.'\"]\')')
```

This one would get me the rows with a specific disease and by using php count() on the result I get an int as 3 which is OK but I haven't got to put it as I expect filter and differentiate new and recurrent cases.

Thanks,
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a pivot table instead of storing multiple id in a single column.

Comment: @RossWilson doesn't laravel manage that for you?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. You would need to create the table yourself. Laravel will allow you to set up relationships in your models but it won't do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the deseaseTreated column is json, couldn't you add an isNew key and when the patient comes in for a second visit, flip that key to false or something similar?

Now when you want to make the report you can get counts on all of them.

```
//example deseaseTreated value 
{
  "deseases": [
    {
      "deseaseID":"Value", 
      "isNew":Boolean,
      ...
    }, 
    {...}
  ]
}
$records = DB::select('select * from treatment');
$diseases = DB::select('select * from diseases');
foreach ($diseases as $disease) {
    $disease['count_new'] = 0;
}
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $json = json_decode($record['diseaseTreated']);
    foreach ($json['diseases'] as disease_index) {
    if ($disease_index['isNew']) {
        foreach ($diseases as &$d) {
            if ($d['diseaseID'] == $disease_index['diseaseID']) {
                $d['count_new']++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```